# Why isn't my equals method working?

Tags: java, equals

I'm using an `ArrayList`, and at one point in the program I'm using the contains method to check if a certain item is contained in the `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` holds objects of type `CharProfile`, a custom class, and it's seeing if a char is contained within it.

So it's using the equals method in the contains method, I assume. So something like `CharProfile.contains(char)`, but it's not working.

I overrode the equals method in CharProfile:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this.character == (Character)o) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So it should be using my equals method when CharProfile is trying to use it, right? So why won't it work?

(In terms of "not working" I'm referring to the fact that `contains` always returns false.)

Comment: You overrode equals and are using contains?

Comment: Where in the ArrayList documentation it is said that ArrayList.contains(Character) will use your supplied equals method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are comparing a reference type using ==, which is wrong. You must use `equals`, with proper `null`-checks added.

But this is just the beginning. Your main problem is that you are trying to compare a `CharProfile` object to a `Character` object. You probably need this instead:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  return o instanceof CharProfile 
     && this.character.equals((CharProfile)o).character;
}
```

This assumes that your `character` field is never null. If it can be null, you need to check that before dereferencing it, as well.

Comment: Instead of the `instanceof` check, I prefer `o.getClass().equals(this.getClass())`.  The former returns true if `o` is a subclass, whereas due to the requirement of symmetry it must almost certainly return false for subclasses.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Yes, I'm fully aware of that one, but most of the time there are no subclasses involved. The advantage of my approach is conciseness because `instanceof` doubles as a null-check as well.

Comment: As Effective Java points out, if you have a value class with equality, you shouldn't be allowing subclassing anyway.  +1 for `instanceof` over `getClass()`, with the qualifier that the class should be final anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding equals such that it test for equality of reference, the default behavior of the operator `==`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)(). You can also make it a oneliner and be more explicit in your cast.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Character && this.character.equals(Character.class.cast(o));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the equals() method and DO NOT forget to override the hashCode() method as well. They go hand in hand.

Some people don't know this, but if using eclipse you can right click choose Source-> and Generate hashCode() and equals()...

But, I suggest that you learn what they're for first before using this convenience.

Answer (score 0):

For example, You have `CharProfile` as below.

```
List<CharProfile> list = new ArrayList<CharProfile>();
list.add(new CharProfile('a'));
list.add(new CharProfile('b'));
list.add(new CharProfile('c'));
```

When `list.contains('a')` is does, the JVM will not call `Override` `equals()` method of `CharProfile`.

For more clear;

```
public class Data {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("I am data");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When `list.contains(new Data())` is does, the JVM will not call `Override` `equals()` method of `Data`.
Now, You will get message like **I am data.**.